# Prevent input datalist from automatically opening upon receiving initial keyboard focus

Tags: html, internet-explorer, input, html-datalist

I have an HTML5 drop-down control, configured similar to this:

```
<input id="textCtrl" list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

I also give this control focus upon the page-load event:

```
//It's done via JQuery, but it makes no difference for this question
$(function () {
    //Set focus to the text control
    $('#textCtrl').focus();
};
```

So what happens, is that when the page loads in IE, or whatever it's called in Windows 10, the drop-down list is opened automatically upon page load, which looks kinda weird. So I would like to keep it initially closed:

[image]

Here, you can [try it](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist) for yourself.

So, is there any way to avoid this list from opening upon page load while the text input has initial keyboard focus?

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal answer, but the following works for me:

```
// Temporarily remove the list from the input and set focus
$("#textCtrl").removeAttr("list").focus();

// Restore the list to the input - if this is done immediately
// the datalist is shown on focus so use a timer to delay adding
// the list.
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#textCtrl").attr("list","browser");
},1);
```